# Trying to add tabbed pane in tabbed pane in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

This is my window which displays a tabbed pane. Inside one of the tabs I want another tabbed pane (with two tabs: tab3, and tab4). I thought this is how you would do it.

```
            Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
                title: 'Package Details for ' + record.data.name,
                height: 200,
                width: 400,
                layout: 'fit',
                items:{
                    xtype: 'tabpanel',
                    items: [{

                        title: 'tab1',
                        xtype: 'tabpanel',
                        items: [{
                            items: [{
                                title: 'tab3'
                            },{
                                title: 'tab4'
                            }]
                        }]
                    },{
                        title: 'tab2'
                    }]
                }
            }).show();
```

But that seems to be wrong because this is what I see :

[image]

Anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: You over-nested the items.

Comment: answer so i can accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't nest items of tabpanel in tab1 in another items. That's called overnesting Evan mentions.